# Tekton error , how to fix: Error executing command: fork/exec /tekton/scripts/script-2-m6dkb

Tags: docker, kubernetes, tekton

I'm getting this error for one of the tekton steps. How do I fix?

- macos, docker-kubernetes

```
Error executing command: fork/exec /tekton/scripts/script-2-m6dkb: no such file or directory
```

```yaml
---
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Task
metadata:
  name: build-images
spec:
  params:
    - name: person
      description: Name of person to greet
      default: John
      type: string
  steps:
    - name: build
      image: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug-v0.19.0
      command:
        - /busybox/sh
        - -c
        - echo test
    - name: say-hello
      image: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug-v0.19.0
      command:
        - /busybox/sh
      args: ['-c', 'echo Hello $(params.person)']
    - name: write-hello #Tekton thsi step fails! Error executing command: fork/exec /tekton/scripts/script-2-m6dkb: no such file or directory
      image: registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi
      script: |
              #!/user/bin/env bash
              echo Preparing greeting
              echo Hello $(params.person) > ~/hello.txt
              sleep 2
              echo Done!
---
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: TaskRun
metadata:
  name: build-images
spec:
  taskRef:
    name: build-images
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the third container of your Task (write-hello), replace  `#!/user/bin/env bash`

Should be: `#!/usr/bin/env bash`